# Specify output PDF based on latex condition

Tags: miktex, exam, jobname

I am using the exam class and miktex for homework assignments. I regularly switch between "\noprintanswers", for the assignment, and "\printanswers", for the solution. I would love to be able to specify something like:

```
\ifprintanswers \output{hw_sol.pdf} \else \output{hw.pdf} \fi
```

However, it doesn't seem to be possible to specify the output save on the very first line, using

```
%& -job-name=hw_sol
```

This, of course, cannot use latex commands. Is there a hack I can use? Maybe inspect the job-name, see if "sol" occurs in it, and if so enable printanswers?

Comment: I have a related issue, and I just set both the flags and the `jobname` from the command line.